# Como pasar datos de una tabbla a Otra

Tags: sql, sql-server, mssql

Necesito insert datos de una tabla a otra
Esta es la tabla Origen

Tabla **Mitablaorigen**

```
+-------+---------+-------+--------+
|usuario|persojaje| CharID|ID-UNICO|
+-------+---------+-------+--------+
|kjsahd | 1324545 |email1 |   500  |
+-------+---------+-------+--------+
|aadsa  | 312321  |email2 |   60   |
+-------+---------+-------+--------+
|asdas  | 2255888 |email3 |   7    |
+-------+---------+-------+--------+
|asdas  | asdasd  |email3 |   7    |
+-------+---------+-------+--------+
```

quiero insetar en esta otra sin  agregar mas columnas de las que tiene
Mi Tabla **Mitabladestino**

```
   +-------+-------+---------+-------+---------+
    |usuario|Pasword|ID-UNICO|Email  | Fecha   |
    +-------+-------+--------+-------+---------+
    |kjsahd |alsdka |   1    |email1 | 01/01/21|
    +-------+-------+--------+-------+---------+
    |aadsa  |342    |   2    |email2 | 25/01/21|
    +-------+-------+--------+-------+---------+
    |asdas  |24324  |   3    |email3 | 45/01/21|
    +-------+-------+--------+-------+---------+
```

quiero solo pasar solo las columnas

Usuario y UserUID

Se  que es algo como este pero este sirve para pasar la misma cantidad de columnas con iguales nombes de una base de datos a otra.

```
INSERT table Mitabladestino (usuario,Pasword,UserUID,Email)
SELECT usuario,Pasword,UserUID,Email
FROM Mitablaorigen
```

creo que seria algo como esto:

```
INSERT table Mitabladestino (usuario,Pasword,UserUID,Email,fecha)
SELECT usuario,UserUID
FROM Mitablaorigen
```

El detalle que tengo valores KEY not NULL y no default, Adicional el UserUID debe ser unico osea el select debe solo insertar los ID que no esten registrados  por que me da este error:

**Msg 544, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Users_Master' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.**

Comment: El `INSERT` deberia solo llevar las columnas a las que vas a usar es decir `INSERT table Mitabladestino (usuario,UserUID)` y por supuesto, el resto de las columnas deberían poder ser `NULL`

Comment: Pues no no son null por que no se quiere ni se puede ni podran ser jamas null

Comment: @JuanCarlosVillamizarAlvarez cómo generas las tablas con los datos ? ***+-------+-------+---------+-------+---------+***

Answer (score 1):

Lo que buscas podría hacerse:

```
INSERT table Mitabladestino (usuario,UserUID)
SELECT usuario,
       UserUID
       FROM Mitablaorigen
```

El tema, es que las otras columnas de `Mitabladestino` deberían poder ser `NULL` si no lo son, hay que inicializarlas con algún valor, por ejemplo algo así:

```
SET
INSERT table Mitabladestino (usuario,Pasword,UserUID,Email,fecha)
SELECT usuario,
       '',
       UserUID, 
       '',
       GETDATE()
       FROM Mitablaorigen
```

El otro tema es:

> Msg 544, Level 16, State 1, Line 6 Cannot insert explicit value for
> identity column in table 'Users_Master' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to
> OFF.

Este error, NO te está diciendo que hay valores repetidos, lo que te está diciendo es que no puedes insertar un valor explícito en una columna que es IDENTITY. Puedes resolver esto, modificando este comportamiento para poder insertar:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Mitabladestino ON

INSERT table Mitabladestino (usuario,UserUID)
SELECT usuario,
       UserUID
       FROM Mitablaorigen

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Mitabladestino OFF
```

Con el `SET IDENTITY_INSERT Mitabladestino ON` hacemos que la tabla pueda recibir valores explícitos, eventualmente, ¿podría haber algún ID repetido? si lo hay claramente tendrás otro error, si quieres que esto no pase, hay  que verificar los valores a insertar:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Mitabladestino ON

INSERT table Mitabladestino (usuario,UserUID)
SELECT usuario,
       UserUID
       FROM Mitablaorigen
       WHERE UserUID NOT IN (SELECT UserUID FROM Mitabladestino)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Mitabladestino OFF
```

Comment: Si pero los UserUID son Keys que son mi principalk problema necesito tomar solo los UserUID que no estan insertados TODOS se repiten mas de 1 vez hasta millones de veces

Comment: Es lo que intenté responderte en mi último código.

Comment: lo que preguntastes si si hay valores repetidos como se haria?

Comment: `WHERE UserUID NOT IN (SELECT UserUID FROM Mitabladestino)` insertarías solo las filas dónde no exista el `UserUID`